# React Formik bind the external button click with onSubmit function in <Formik>

Tags: reactjs, submit, formik

I'm trying to submit the form by using the external buttons which are located outside of `<Form>` or `<Formik>` tags

As shown in the following screenshot, my button is in Bootstrap > Modal Footer section and they are outside of form tag.  I'm trying to submit the form when the user clicks on the `Submit` button.

[image]

Please see the similar code as the following.  I uploaded it onto [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jlx4vq1l9w).

```
function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Formik
            initialValues={{
              date: '10/03/2019',
              workoutType: "Running",
              calories: 300
            }}
            onSubmit={values => {
              console.log(values);
            }}
            render={({ values }) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment>
                  <Form>
                    Date: <Field name="date" />
                    <br />
                    Type: <Field name="workoutType" />
                    <br />                
                    Calories: <Field name="calories" />
                    <br />  
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                  </Form>
                  <hr />
                  <br />
                  <button type="submit" onClick={() => this.props.onSubmit}>
                    Button Outside Form
                  </button>
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            }}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Since the button is outside of the form, it doesn't trigger Submit behaviour and I don't know how to connect this button's action and `Formik OnSubmit` method.  If I moved that button inside form tag, it works as expected and I don't have to do anything special.

I tried to follow this SO's post [React Formik use submitForm outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525057/react-formik-use-submitform-outside-formik) .  But I really couldn't figure out how it works.

I tried to bind the button click action like `onClick={() => this.props.onSubmit}` as mentioned in the post.  But it's not doing anything or showing any error.

Could you please help me how I can bind the Submit button outside of the form with 'OnSubmit' function in Formik?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It appears you have access to the `submitForm` method as a property of the argument passed to the `render` function. Simply call that with the `button`'s `onClick` handler...

```
render={({ submitForm, ...restOfProps}) => {
    console.log('restOfProps', restOfProps);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Form>
            Date: <Field name="date" />
            <br />
            Type: <Field name="workoutType" />
            <br />                
            Calories: <Field name="calories" />
            <br />  
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </Form>
            <hr />
            <br />
            <button type="submit" onClick={submitForm}>
            Button Outside Form
            </button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Formik's render give you a callback param `handleSubmit`. Assign this to the `<button`.

Since your `button` is not in the form, change its type to `<button type="button"...` and assign the onClick to `onClick={handleSubmit}`

Update the render as follow,

```
render={({ values, handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Form>
        Date: <Field name="date" />
        <br />
        Type: <Field name="workoutType" />
        <br />
        Calories: <Field name="calories" />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
      <hr />
      <br />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Button Outside Form
        </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the handleSubmit function is never called, replace `onClick={() => this.props.onSubmit}` with `onClick={props.handleSubmit}`

edit: since it looks like you need a little more directions, here is an edited version of the linked code sandbox, the correct prop is `handleSubmit` and you need to destructure it from the props just like you did with values.

https://codesandbox.io/s/qz2jnlp929

Comment: It's showing "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" error

Answer (score -2):

Just use `onClick={handlesubmit}` in your external Button component making sure to destructure the handlesubmit function from the Formik component. Please have a look;

```
<Formik
initialValues={{field: true}}
onSubmit={() => console("Submited via my onSubmit function")}
>

{({ handleSubmit }) => (

  <Form>
          <Field
            name="field"
            placeholder="Date"
          />
  </Form>

  <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
    Save
  </Button>

</Formik>
```