# Is there a way to call multiple function in onClick method without having to provide arguments?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have two functions but do not have their argument and i just want to run the two functions on a button's onClick method.

I know the following code works on react.

```
onClick={handleSubmit}
```

Is it possible to do something like

```
onClick={handleSubmit; doSomethingElse;}
```

Inside the onClick method i need to call the Formik's handleSubmit method. Note: I am trying to call the handleSubmit method from a button outside the form.

[React Formik bind the external button click with onSubmit function in <Formik>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093120/react-formik-bind-the-external-button-click-with-onsubmit-function-in-formik)

As explained in this article i can just `onClick={handleSubmit}` do this to call the function. But i also need to call another function on the same onClick function. How can i call both of them from the same onClick?

Comment: Just try something like this `onClick={() => { handleSubmit(); doSomething(); }}`

Comment: I do not have the arguments for the handleSubmit and doSomething method.

Comment: We dont need arguments for the above mentioned `onClick`.

Comment: What do you mean by ` don't have arguments for handleSubmit and doSomething`?

Comment: @PradipShrestha Please post some code where you facing the issue.

Comment: You are facing this because you have `submit` button outside of your `form` tag. Just give an id to your form, for example, `myForm` and update your `submit` button with `<button form="myForm"> Submit</button>`. That's all.

Comment: @SelvaTS updated.

Answer (score 2):

Just create another function and call both your function in the third one.

```js
function auxilaryFunction (e) {
 handleSubmit(e);
 doSomethingElse(e);
}
```

Then update `onClick` method like following:-

```js
onClick={auxilaryFunction}
```

Now it will call both your functions. If you don't want to use `e` (event) then simply removed it from both of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick={this.handleClick}

handleClick(){
   function1();
   function2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make function like

```
handleSubmit = () => {
  this.doSomethingElse();
  this.doSomethingElse();
```

}
when click on handleSubmit automatic functions called inside the function