# Formik Showing Error on Empty Field As Well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik, yup

When I open the screen, I don't see any validation error until I first submit the form. Once the email address is entered correctly and the form is submitted by hitting the button, the form logic works correctly. An alert is shown & the field is reset (intentional)

However, once I close the the alert, Formik still shows me an error that I must enter an email address (required field). Is it possible to reset the error too? Just like it was when I first opened the screen? I want this error to appear only when I am submitting the form without typing something.

[image]

Snippets of my code:

Resetting the value here:

```
 const initialValues: FormValues = {
    email: '',
  };


const handleSubmitForm = React.useCallback(
    (values: FormValues, helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>) => {
      console.log('Submitted');
      loadUsers({
        variables: {
          where: { email: values.email },
        },
      });
      values.email = '';
    },
    [loadUsers],
  );
```

```
 <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}>
                {({
                  handleChange,
                  handleBlur,
                  handleSubmit,
                  values,
                }) => (
                  <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
                    <View 
                    style={styles.form}
                    >
                      <FieldInput 
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                        handleBlur={handleBlur}
                        value={values.email}
                        fieldType="email"
                      />
                      <ErrorMessage 
                        name="email"
                        render={(msg) => ( 
                          <Text style={styles.errorText}>
                            {msg}
                          </Text>
                        )}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                      <Button
                        rounded
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={handleSubmit}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>
                          Add Friend{' '}
                        </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`setFieldError`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfielderror-field-string-errormsg-string--void) or [`setErrors`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#seterrors-fields--field-string-string---void).

I'm not sure where exactly you want to clear the error, but if isn't inside the form, you can get a `ref` of the formik component and call `setFieldError` or `setErrors`.

e.g.

```
setFieldError('email', undefined)
```

---

**Other observations about your code that isn't related to the question**

Doing `values.email = '';` isn't a good thing, if you want to reset the value of `email` you should use [`setFieldValue`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void), just like you will use `setFieldError`.

e.g.

```
helpers.setFieldValue('email', '')
```

Comment: setFieldError and setErrors can only be used within the Formik wrapper right? If I pass them along with handleSubmit, values etc..Will that reset the error?

Comment: @a125 you can use `setFieldError` and `setErrors` outside the formik wrapper as I said in my answer. If you are confused in how to get the `ref` and call `setFieldError`, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525057/react-formik-use-submitform-outside-formik)  where it shows how to call `handleSubmit`. In you case is the same, but instead of `handleSubmit`, you will call `setFieldError`.