# ReactJS, Formik, Bootstrap Modal - Submit from modal button

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, formik

I have the following structure in my ReactJS App - [CodeSandBox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-swanson-kbu9p?file=/src/App.js).
I'm trying to somehow submit the Formik form by using a button of Bootstrap modal window, however I am unable to understand how to call the form submission from 2 components down the tree and bring the functions together.

Could someone kindly advise whether it's even something that can be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: You never use your `FormFields` in the modal so I don't understand the problem clearly

Comment: There is a Formik form field "Title" that is being used inside the Modal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Formik use submitForm outside <Formik />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525057/react-formik-use-submitform-outside-formik)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the **FormFields** component, you need to add an `id` to your form

```
<Form id="fooId">
```

and for the modal button you add the `form` and `type` attribute like:

```
<Button
 ...
 type="submit"
 form="fooId"
 ...
/>
```

And the form would be submitted. You can skip passing the `onClick` event to that button and pass the `doSubmit` method to the `Formik` component in **FormFields** component.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-cray-30e8g)